# filter and print array in a more readable way

Tags: php, arrays

```
$sql = "select * from banners where bgroup > ''";
$st = $db->prepare($sql);
$st->execute();
$data = $st->fetchAll();
print_r($data);
```

Result (multidimensional array):

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
            [id] => 59 
            [0] => 59 
            [date] => 2018-11-23 23:44:47 
            [1] => 2018-11-23 23:44:47 
            [src] => banners/5b5ccafff3f6a.jpg 
            [2] => banners/5b5ccafff3f6a.jpg 
            [name] => abc 
            [3] => abc 
    ) 
    [1] => Array... 
    [2] => Array...
```

I want to filter the above - to get only those sub-arrays where `name = abc` and print them without indexes and separated by a new line.

Like this:

```
Array(
    Array{
        [id] => 59
        [date] => 2018-11-23 23:44:47
```

Any help?

Comment: use var_export()

Comment: Why not filter the data in sql first and than just handle the output in php ? Something like this: `select * from banners where bgroup > '' AND name = 'abc'`  ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Comment: @IgorIlic, in that case I need to go to SQL server multiple times. It's better to get data at once

Comment: for separation in new lines view the sourcecode in the browser - firefox shows it like you would expect. but print_r always shows indexes...

Comment: Maybe you could use `array_filter` for this; checkout the docs here: [PHP documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change query as well as fetch mode to get desired output directly:-

```
$st = $db->prepare("SELECT * from banners WHERE name = ? AND bgroup > ''");
$st->execute(array('abc'));
$data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
print_r($data);
```

Note:- use `prepared statements` properly and fully.

Reference:-[PDOStatement::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Answer (score 1):

Way 1:
 modify your sql query to look like following:

```
$sql = "select * from banners where name='abc' AND bgroup > ''";
```

Way 2 (Less efficient then the one above):

```
$newArr = [];

foreach($results as $result)
{
    if($result['name'] == 'abc')
    {
        $newArr[] = $result;   
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($newArr);
```

Comment: first way is better, of course, but I'm affraid it is high cost regarding performances. My post is simplified, in reality , in case of first solution I would need to go to SQL server +50 times. I think it's better to get data at once

Comment: @qadenza  you only need to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` in `$data = $st->fetchAll();` like :- `$data = $st->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` . check now and let me know worked or not?

Comment: @AlivetoDie excellent for avoiding print indexes, thanks a lot. And yes - in source code view - I'm getting what I want. Your comment is the answer, in fact